# Magento serial codes

Tags: php, magento, serial-number, product-key

I'm using 'Serial Codes' from 'ModifyMage Solutions' to send serial codes when somebody is buying a product.

Does anybody knows how to send the serial codes ON PAYMENT?
Not on checkout, because that's simple, but ON PAYMENT?

Thanx in advance

Comment: Why you doesn't write to authors?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to edit your settings. The module can be configured to automatically issue Serial Codes on checkout success, or when an order is invoiced and paid. Source: http://www.modifymage.com/

Here's the important and relevant bits:

- Choose to automatically issue Serial Codes based on customer group, checkout success, or when an order is invoiced and paid. Supports the option to create multiple invoices per order.
- Automatically assign Serial Codes to deferred payment orders as "Pending" without actually issuing them to the customer until the order is invoiced. Allows for more effective tracking and inventory control. Pending codes are automatically returned to "Available" status if the order is cancelled.
- Automatically withhold issuing of Serial Codes for standard Magento deferred payment methods ('Check or Money Order,' 'Cash On Delivery,' 'Bank Transfer') with the ability to notify customers that Serial Codes will be issued upon receipt of payment. Additional deferred payment methods from specific payment modules are also supported.